# Spinner in html5 input box with type text?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser

I have a text box which can take both metric and imperial unit system. The problem is that for me to enable that, the input type of textbox has to be changed from number to text.

The previous box was -

```
<input id="thickness" type="number" value="10" min="2" max="100" step="1" />
```

The current box is -

```
<input id="thickness" type="text" value="10" min="2" max="100" step="1" />
```

HTML5 does not support spinner in text type. Is there any other work around to support native HTML5 spinner in text type without adding external support from JS?

Comment: Sorry can you explain why it needs to be text? both imperial and metric are numbers... If you want to use pure html5 then no, it needs to be type number.

Comment: Because the imperial system needs to be represented with single and double quotation. Cannot do that by keeping the input number it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML5 even if it has a lot of components good for doing your work is just a frontend,so if you need to change something that the user does not need to see, you have to go with JS (or Jquery), you can replace the DOM of your input with Jquery.

Comment: I am trying to use spinner() method of jquery-ui. Thanks for your input

Comment: Be careful about your scope view of spinner() method.
Reading "I'm trying" it makes me suggest you're having some problems with it. just feel free to ask me

Comment: I've created a custom spinner and had to use string (eg - 10 cm) in the spinner. I have done that, the only problem I'm facing is that the spin event does not fire in first time the spinner is used. After any other event has been fired it works as it is supposed to. focusout works fine though, just spin event is not working

Comment: Not able to guess your problem without a full code, please open another question with the code and tell if you are using frameworks/libraries or you're coding by yourself. then tag me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858490/spin-event-doesnt-trigger-at-first-time-in-jquery-spinner