# spin event doesn't trigger at first time in jquery spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a custom spinner which appends a string after a number.

```
var percent = 5.5%;
$.widget("ui.pcntspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
        _format: function(value){
            return value + " %";
        },

        _parse: function(value){
            return parseInt(value);
        }
    });


    $("#spinner").pcntspinner().val(percent);
```

The spinner has two events attached to it i.e. focusout and spin. focusout works fine in first call too, but spin does not gets triggered at first time. Only after any other event has been triggered does the spin gets called. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: The code seems well written, is not a bad code.
I think that maybe is a problem of asynchronous calls.
When in my code something is well written and does not work, there's a 99% problem that comes from understanding the flow of the program

Comment: I've posted what worked for me. Still not sure that why `widgetEventPrefix` was required in the spinner widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I still don't understand though why spin was not getting triggered the first time but this helped -

```
var percent = 5.5%;
$.widget("ui.pcntspinner", $.ui.spinner, {

         widgetEventPrefix: "spin",
        _format: function(value){
            return value + " %";
        },

        _parse: function(value){
            return parseInt(value);
        }
    });


    $("#spinner").pcntspinner().val(percent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the widget so `spin` won't work you need `_spin`

```
$.widget("ui.pcntspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    _format: function(value){
        return value + " %";
    },

    _parse: function(value){
        return parseInt(value);
    },

    _spin: function( event, ui ) { 
       alert('value updated by :' + ui);

       if(validation){
         var result = this._super( event, ui ); 
         return result; //<-- important for generic functionality
       }else
       {
         //returning nothing would make value not change
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work, spin event is still not fired even when I use _spin function in my spinner